# How to use rsync for Windows on both ends?

Tags: windows-10, rsync, git-bash

I install rsync for Windows through git-bash. If the remote end is Linux, it works fine. However, it does not work if the remote end is Windows. I install rsync on the remote end and test working as well, but it seems somehow it cannot locate its counterpart on the remote end.

```
$ rsync file user@host:
'rsync' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [sender=3.2.3]
```

Note, ssh and scp between the two Windows work well.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this scenario, but first, open Windows terminal on the remote machine and/or ssh session and type `rsync` - is that command found? If not, either add it to the PATH environment variable or use `--rsync-path=` argument - see the [man](https://manpages.org/rsync) for details.

I found at https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2103650-syncing-files-from-linux-to-windows-need-rsync-that-works that people use workarounds like making an NFS share or installing cwrsync.

Comment: verified working, a path issue indeed